# Filter emails by domain using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using `javamail` to download emails, but now I need to filter some email address by domain.

I try to use the `FromStringTerm` but I can't know the correct pattern to filter it.

**edit 1**: the *jmehrens* solved partially my problem. I would like to filter when i get messages from folder, something like:

```
            Store store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect(configc.host, configc.email, configc.pass);
            Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message[] arrayMessages1 = folderInbox.search(??);
```

How can I filter by domain at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FromStringTerm inherits the behavior described in [javax.mail.search.SearchTerm](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/StringTerm.html):

> This class implements the match method for Strings. The current implementation provides only for substring matching. We could add comparisons (like strcmp ...).

So there is no pattern as it performs substring matching out of the box.

Here is a test case:

```
public class DomainMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage((Session) null);
        msg.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("foo@bar.org"));
        msg.saveChanges();

        System.out.println(new FromStringTerm("@bar.org").match(msg));
        System.out.println(new FromStringTerm("@spam.org").match(msg));
    }
}
```

Using the [javax.mail.Folder::search](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) documentation you would write something like:

```
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect(configc.host, configc.email, configc.pass);
Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

Message[] onlyBarOrg = folderInbox.search(new FromStringTerm("@bar.org"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply jmehrens. I updated my question giving some details about what i need to do.